# Recordset to timespan

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, adodb

I have a table which have a time(7) type field named Shift_Start_Time

After creating the recordset RST.

I want to keep it in a timespan

```
TimeSpan  TT;
TT = RST.Fields("Shift_Start_Time").Value;
```

or 
keep it into milliseconds as integer

```
int int1;

int1 = RST.Fields("Shift_Start_Time").Value;
```

How can i do that? Every step i have taked it gives the similer errors.
for example:

```
Convert.ToInt64(RST.Fields("Shift_Start_Time").Value);

"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[]' to type 'System.IConvertible'."
```

Comment: BTW, do you mean RecordSet, or DataSet? RecordSet is ancient and should not be used.

Comment: I am using ADODB.RecordSet not dataset.

Comment: Yeah, that's ancient, pre-.NET stuff. You should move into the 21st Century. At least move to ADO.NET, assuming you don't want to make the jump all the way to the ADO.NET Entity Framework.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I am beginner,just learning every staffs and thanks for the advice.

Comment: Yeah, you don't want to begin with a technology which is over a decade in the past.

Comment: Yes. Of course i don't. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use it as an `Int64` or a `DateTimeOffset`. The code might look something like this:

```
var bytes = RST.Fields("Shift_Start_Time").Value as byte[];
var intVal = BitConverter.ToInt64(bytes, 0);
var dtOffset = new DateTimeOffset(intVal, new TimeSpan(-5, 0, 0));
```

In this example I've used a static `-5` offset for `EST` in the `TimeSpan`. [See this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/usisvde/archive/2007/11/14/time-for-ado-net.aspx) for more detail.

Comment: Why not do a direct cast to `byte[]`? `(byte[]) RST.Fields("Shift_Start_Time").Value` will never be `null`.